# Relational loop in my database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm working on sport club database design and I have a problem with loops there. First I'd like to show you my diagram (I'm sorry i don't have professional for design in this place).
[image]

I know that doing such loops should be avoided, but if there a reason for each of them? For example - I have four tables - players, teams, games and participants. There are always two teams in each game - my team and opponents. So I need to add foreign key team_id to the game table. Next I have players, each player is currently playing in specific team co there is [many - one] relation between these two tables. And I want to keep somewhere stats about 'this' player in 'this' game - participants table. What more - I need to keep info about some of my players in transfers table, so there is another loop. But can I keep that design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider changing your table designs.

In the games table:

- you should remove part_Id since you describe participants in your participants table.
- both team_id and opp_id should be foreign keys to your teams table

In the participants table

- you should remove the part_id primary key, add team_id and use team_id, player_id and game_id as the primary key since one player cannot play on both teams

In your players table

- you should remove team_Id And use this table to describe the players

You should create a new table that describes the members of a team with team_id and player_id being the primary kekey combined.

In your transfers table you should have a transfer id, player id , team 1 and team 2. New additions to this table should signal a need to update the new team members table.

Answer (score 1):

Circular references naturally exists between "real world" entities.
So the rule should be understand like we need to avoid RDBMS managed integrity support on circular references.

Which FK/PK references should be removed (and additional information should be stored with entity) is another question and answer depends on your needs.

Usually fixing "dynamic event" in RDBMS (like transffers or games) "saves" all info and do not need use any fk. AKA Transaction Processing.